# Returning value from a loop in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to return some values from a loop with or without using a function. My current script is like this, here I am interested in retrieving the value "parameter" and the individual values might be something like this -
general_option=true, targeted_option=true, minReads=2, mxVariants=10, target_interval=/path/to/file.txt, minimumReads=4, cap_dup=2;

```
def analysis_parameters(general_option, targeted_option, minReads, mxVariants, target_interval, minimumReads, cap_dup):
if general_option is 'true':
    parameters=['--minReads='+minReads+' --maxVariants='+mxVariants]
    return parameters
elif targeted_option is 'true':
    parameters=['--regions='+target_interval+' --minReads='+minimumReads+' --filterDuplicates='+cap_dup]
    return parameters
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a single `return` statement?

```
if general_option is 'true':
    parameters = ['--minReads=' + minReads + ' --maxVariants=' + mxVariants]
elif targeted_option is 'true':
    parameters = ['--regions=' + target_interval + ' --minReads=' + minimumReads + ' --filterDuplicates=' + cap_dup]
return parameters
```